# problem getting forked process to read from STDIN using pipes

Tags: c++, linux, pipe, fork

I am trying to create a helper class to execute a system command and get response back with piping support. For the cases where I need to get the response only (no STDIN to consume for the command) it is working as expected, for pipe support, I am getting garbled STDIN and I can not find out the root cause.

The main function which handles this mechanism is (please ignore the minor error check issues)

the minimal working example

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/prctl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

struct exec_cmd_t {
    exec_cmd_t(std::vector<std::string> args) : args(args), has_executed(false), cpid(-1) { }
    exec_cmd_t(const exec_cmd_t &) = delete;
    exec_cmd_t(exec_cmd_t &&) = delete;
    exec_cmd_t & operator=(const exec_cmd_t &) = delete;
    exec_cmd_t & operator=(exec_cmd_t &&) = delete;

    std::string operator()();

    std::string pipe_cmd(const std::string & input);
    std::string pipe_cmd();
    ~exec_cmd_t();

    private:
    std::vector<std::string> args;
    bool has_executed;
    int cpid;
    std::stringstream in_stream;
    std::stringstream out_stream;

    friend std::string operator | (exec_cmd_t & first, exec_cmd_t & second);
    friend std::string operator | (exec_cmd_t && first, exec_cmd_t && second);
    friend std::string operator | (std::string, exec_cmd_t & second);
    friend std::string operator | (std::string, exec_cmd_t && second);
};

std::string exec_cmd_t::pipe_cmd(const std::string & input) {
    this->has_executed = true;
    const int read_end = 0;
    const int write_end = 1;

    int read_pipe[2];
    int write_pipe[2];

    if (pipe(read_pipe) < 0 || pipe(write_pipe) < 0) {
        this->has_executed = false;
        return std::string{};
    }

    this->in_stream << input;
    std::string line;
    while(getline(this->in_stream, line)) {
        if (line.size() == 0) {
            continue;
        }
       int wr_sz = write(write_pipe[write_end], line.c_str(), line.size());
       if (wr_sz <= 0) {
           break;
       }
       write(write_pipe[write_end], "\n", 1);
    }
    close(write_pipe[write_end]);

    this->cpid = fork();
    if (this->cpid == 0) {
        dup2(write_pipe[read_end], STDIN_FILENO);
        dup2(read_pipe[write_end], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(read_pipe[read_end]);
        close(write_pipe[write_end]);
        close(read_pipe[write_end]);
        close(write_pipe[read_end]);
        prctl(PR_SET_PDEATHSIG, SIGTERM);
        char * params[args.size()];
        const char * image_path = args[0].c_str();
        for(int i = 1; i < args.size(); i++) {
            params[i-1] = const_cast<char *>(args[i].c_str());
        }
        params[args.size()] = nullptr;
        execv(image_path, params);
        exit(1);
    }

    close(read_pipe[write_end]);
    close(write_pipe[read_end]);

    char buff[256];
    int rd_sz = -1;
    int flags = fcntl(read_pipe[0], F_GETFL, 0);
    fcntl(read_pipe[read_end], F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
    int status = 0;
    waitpid(this->cpid, &status, 0);
    this->has_executed = false;
    int error_code = 0;
    while((rd_sz = read(read_pipe[read_end], buff, sizeof(buff))) > 0) {
        buff[rd_sz] = '\0';
        this->out_stream << std::string{buff};
    }
    close(read_pipe[read_end]);
    return this->out_stream.str();
}


std::string exec_cmd_t::pipe_cmd() {
    static std::string empty_str{};
    return pipe_cmd(empty_str);
}

std::string exec_cmd_t::operator()() {
    return pipe_cmd();
}

exec_cmd_t::~exec_cmd_t() {
    if (this->has_executed) {
        int status;
        waitpid(this->cpid, &status, WNOHANG);
        if (!WIFEXITED(status)) {
            kill(this->cpid, SIGKILL);
            waitpid(this->cpid, &status, 0);
        }
    }
}

std::string operator | (exec_cmd_t & first, exec_cmd_t & second) {
    return second.pipe_cmd(first());
}

std::string operator | (exec_cmd_t && first, exec_cmd_t && second) {
    return second.pipe_cmd(first());
}

std::string operator | (std::string output, exec_cmd_t & second) {
    return second.pipe_cmd(output);
}

std::string operator | (std::string output, exec_cmd_t && second) {
    return second.pipe_cmd(output);
}

int main() {
    auto str = exec_cmd_t{ {"/bin/echo", "echo", "hello\nworld\nor\nnot"} } | exec_cmd_t{ {"/bin/grep", "grep", "world", "-"} };
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

gives me

```
grep: =V: No such file or directory                                                                                                                                                   
(standard input):world
```

It seems like grep is executing twice, one failing with no such file or directory and another one is succeeding. Any suggestion would be very helpful :-) .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code seems to be C++, so you should remove the C tag. Your code is incomplete. Please show enough code to allow us to compile it and to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Unrelated: Any reason why you remove blank lines? You should probably let the newline through.

Comment: @Bodo I put the c tag because this is more of a c library functionality with probably c++ sugar coating. Now removed the C tag. Will update the question.

Comment: @TedLyngmo nothing much, empty string yields noop for write(_,_,len=0). So, just ignored it for now. But you are right, I might need to use the newline delimiter from the getline() (maybe?).

Comment: Yes, I don't think you should filter out anything in your pipe:ing. It can get confusing later on when you use it in real code and expect the blank lines.

Comment: @TedLyngmo agreed. Thank your for the suggestion :-)

Comment: @fadedreamz I'm not entirely sure, but I think you may get a copy of one (the last) `exec_cmd_t` that you don't count on. Print something unique (like the `args`) in the destructor to make it visible. Perhaps creating copy and move ctors and assignment operators will make it clearer when something goes awry.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Good point, thanks I will update the findings after testing.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I removed copy/move constructor and copy/move assignment (to at least make sure I am not duplicating stuff), still the same problem.

Comment: Ok, I was going to try your code out myself but it seems to be missing some parts. Can you perhaps put together a [mcve]? It looks interesting.

Comment: Code update to reflect minimal reproducible example. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at east one cause for Undefined Behaviour that *may* cause your program to do what it does. You declare and use a VLA out-of-range like this:

```
char* params[args.size()];
...
params[args.size()] = nullptr;
execv(image_path, params);
```

This leaves the terminating `char*` in your `params` uninitialized so it could point anywhere. `grep` thinks it points at a filename, tries to open it and fails.

Since VLA:s aren't in the C++ standard, consider changing it to:

```
std::vector<char*> params(args.size());
...
params[args.size() - 1] = nullptr;
execv(image_path, params.data());
```

Another cause for concern is that you use `int`s where you should have used `ssize_t`s even though it's highly unlikely that you've read or written more than an `int` could handle.

After I made those changes, it started working and printed the expected `world`. I even added a third command to check it could handle it. Suggested changes:

---

```
14,15c14,15
<     exec_cmd_t(std::vector<std::string> args) :
<         args(args), has_executed(false), cpid(-1) {}
---
>     exec_cmd_t(std::vector<std::string> Args) :
>         args(Args), has_executed(false), cpid(-1), in_stream{}, out_stream{} {}
59c59
<         int wr_sz = write(write_pipe[write_end], line.c_str(), line.size());
---
>         ssize_t wr_sz = write(write_pipe[write_end], line.c_str(), line.size());
76c76
<         char* params[args.size()];
---
>         std::vector<char*> params(args.size());
78c78
<         for(int i = 1; i < args.size(); i++) {
---
>         for(decltype(args.size()) i = 1; i < args.size(); i++) {
81,82c81,82
<         params[args.size()] = nullptr;
<         execv(image_path, params);
---
>         params[args.size() - 1] = nullptr;
>         execv(image_path, params.data());
90c90
<     int rd_sz = -1;
---
>     ssize_t rd_sz = -1;
96c96
<     int error_code = 0;
---
>     // int error_code = 0; // unused
106,107c106
<     static std::string empty_str{};
<     return pipe_cmd(empty_str);
---
>     return pipe_cmd({});
143c142,143
<                exec_cmd_t{{"/bin/grep", "grep", "world", "-"}};
---
>                exec_cmd_t{{"/bin/grep", "grep", "-A1", "hello"}} |
>                exec_cmd_t{{"/bin/grep", "grep", "world"}};
```

---

I also realized that your program acts like a proxy between the piped commands, reading everything from one command and writing it to the next.

You could start all programs at the same time and setup the pipes between the started programs in one go. For three commands, you'd need three pipes:

```
                     cmd1  cmd2  cmd3
                     |  w--r  w--r  |
                 stdin              read output into program
or fed by your program
```

This would make performance and memory consumption less of an issue if you decide to run commands with a lot of output. Internally you'd would only need to store what you'd like to store by reading the output from the last command. I made a small test of this approach and it works like a charm.

Comment: thanks, it was the UB (literally never crossed my mind). I was looking for the problem in wrong place. Although VLA works after the fix, but I think your suggestion is much better than VLAs. The performance improvement suggestion is really good one. Thanks again and have a great week!